Huge probability of a long sequence occurring twice in a long file.
While calculating the probability that the same sequence of 50 words occurs twice in a file that contains 400 million random words (each word can have 65536 different states)...
First, I assumed that the 50-word sequence is a permutation with replacements thus it collectively has $65536^{50}$ states.
Next, I assumed that the file can contain (400000000 - 50) such sequences (not $\frac{400000000}{50}$ because the sequence can start at any word of the file). I'd appreciate some comments about this assumption.
I use the birthday formula to calculate the probability that the file does NOT contain 2 identical sequences:
$$
\frac{65536^{50}!}{65536^{50*400000000}(65536^{50}-400000000)!}
$$
However that formula is very hard to calculate due to the huge numbers, so I use the Sterling's formula $n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n $ to approximate the factorials, which yields this monstrosity:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi 65536^{50}}(\frac{65536^{50}}{e})^{(65536^{50})}}{65536^{50*400000000}\sqrt{2\pi (65536^{50}-400000000)}(\frac{65536^{50}-400000000}{e})^{(65536^{50}-400000000)}}
$$
Unfortunately, I cannot find any online tools that can simplify or approximate this monstrosity.
Even the venerable WolframAlpha gives up when presented with such large exponents:

QUESTION 1: Is my approach to this problem correct ?
QUESTION 2: Does anyone have an idea how to simplify this monstrosity or approximate it ?
QUESTION 3: Are there any online tools that can handle it ?

DId you even try to simplify this? it simplifies tremendously before you even need to start evaluating anything

The nice part of the birthday problem is that days don't overlap.  Your problem allows for overlapping sequences, so we cannot merely apply that formula.  What is the source for this problem?

@Brian Moeahring: Someone cheated by copying and pasting a fragment of this file over another part of the same file and now is denying it, claiming it to be a fluke.  The file is used for one-time-pad encryption and the repeating sequence leads to key-reuse.  It is serious.

@MPW:  I tried but I did not get anywhere.  How would you approach it ?

Is each word (in the file of $400$ million words) chosen uniformly and independently at random from the $65536$ available words?

@paw88789: Yes.

As Brian Moehring says in the comments, the birthday paradox does not directly apply here because words can overlap. However, we can get around this and also get away with doing a much simpler calculation, by instead calculating the expected number of collisions. This is an upper bound on the probability that there is at least one collision, so if it ends up being very small (and it will end up being very small) then so is the probability of there being at least one collision.
The huge numbers are a distraction here. In general suppose there are $A$ possible word states and a sequence of $N$ words chosen independently and uniformly at random, and that we are computing the expected number of collisions between two sequences of $L$ words. A sequence can start at $N - L + 1$ different places (it is very easy to be off by one here but as a sanity check this does the right thing when $L = 1$), so there are $N - L + 1$ possible sequences and hence ${N - L + 1 \choose 2}$ pairs of distinct sequences.
The probability that two sequences collide is $\frac{1}{A^L}$ (by independence; as Mike observes in the comments it doesn't matter if they overlap or not), so by linearity of expectation the expected number of collisions is exactly
$$\boxed{ \mathbb{E}(\text{collisions}) = \frac{ {N-L+1 \choose 2} }{A^L} }.$$
So, the denominator here is the massive $65536^{50} \approx 6.7 \times 10^{240}$, while the numerator here is the comparatively puny ${4 \times 10^8 - 50 + 1 \choose 2} \approx 8 \times 10^{16}$. There's no chance; the expected number of collisions is infinitesimal.
Also if whoever this is was right that it was a fluke, so the collision appeared by chance, then you'd expect there to be many other collisions. It's very unlikely for there to be only one; the way the numbers work out, most of the time either you are in a regime where the expected number of collisions is very small or very large. The numbers have to collude for the expected number to be close to $1$.

Thanks for your help!  I am reading it now. Please pop in the comments section once in a while.  I think I'll have questions.

BTW:  Other files generated by this hardware RNG + hashing fn, do not exhibit any such repetitions. I caught it only because the security system is constantly running autocorrelations and other stats on these files.

In that case I think you can very confidently assert that a copy-paste happened.

Yes,  I need to make that argument very cogently in my incident report before the sh!t hits the fan.  I'm still studying your answer.

Could you elaborate some more on the statement "The probability that two non-overlapping sequences collide is $\frac{1}{A^L}$ " ?

What happened to the analysis of the overlapped sequences ?  I remember reading that their number is insignificant compared to the number of non-overlapped sequences, but now I cannot find any mention about them.

@George: 1) This follows from the assumption that the words are chosen independently and uniformly at random. The probability that the $k^{th}$ element of each sequence collides is $\frac{1}{A}$, and these events are all independent (here we need the non-overlapping assumption), so the probabilities multiply. 2) It actually doesn't matter either way because the argument above computes an upper bound, so I removed that part. (This upper bound is an extremely close approximation, but that doesn't matter because the probability is so small either way.)

@George: this argument only bounds the probability that there is a non-overlapping collision and it ignores the overlapping collisions entirely. I assume the collision you're actually interested in is non-overlapping? So it applies to the collision of interest. The non-overlapping collisions are different because e.g. in the string $AAAA$ there is a non-overlapping collision between the first $AAA$ and the second $AAA$, so the analysis is complicated by needing to consider strings which overlap with themselves when translated. But again, this shouldn't matter in your case!

I am getting a lot of objections from my coworkers about the overlapping sequences and I am losing the argument because the ratio of overlapping sequences to non-overlapping ones is not clear in my mind.  I think it is NL but I can't justify it.  Perhaps the following question would be a better one suited to tackling this issue:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4937245/how-to-modify-the-birthday-formula-to-account-for-overlapping-sequences

@QiaochuYuan It is also true that the probability two overlapping sequences collide is $A^{-L}$, so the expected number of total collisions (overlapping or not) is exactly $\binom N2 A^{-L}$. That is, you can get rid of the "non-overlapping" qualifier, and your answer would still be correct (and George would be less confused).

@Mike: ah, you're right, I'd somehow convinced myself it was more complicated than that. Thanks! You need ${N-L+1 \choose 2} A^{-L}$ for the exact exact value but again, in this situation it barely matters.
